# Daylight savings in DataWeave 2.0 dates

Tags: mule, dataweave

is there a way to handle automatically daylight savings? I’m using the following transformation

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{'date': now() >> "EST"}
```

but the output is

```
{
  "date": "2019-08-08T06:45:16.663-05:00"
}
```

The timezone is `-05:00`, but taking daylight saving into account I want it to be `-04:00`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do this is to use relative (name based) timezones.

```
now() >> "America/New_York"
```